# Поиск объекта в массиве с помощью scanner

Tags: java, массивы, scanner

Система авторизации пользователя. Мне нужно выбрать любой объект используя scanner, написав holder, а затем, если он существует в массиве, дописать к нему password, чтобы "авторизоваться", а затем управлять balance этого объекта (переводить число другому пользователю). Долго ломаю голову, как это сделать, никак не выходит.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это написать

```
package BankAccount;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankAccount {

    private final String holder;
    private final String password;
    private double balance;

    public BankAccount(String holder, String password, double balance) {
        this.holder = holder;
        this.password = password;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount[] bankAccounts = new BankAccount[10];
        bankAccounts[0] = new BankAccount("Alex", "alex1234", 1000);
        bankAccounts[1] = new BankAccount("Denis", "denis1234", 1000);
        bankAccounts[2] = new BankAccount("Sergio", "sergio1234", 1000);
        bankAccounts[3] = new BankAccount("Matthew", "matthew1234", 1000);
        bankAccounts[4] = new BankAccount("Dustin", "dustin1234", 1000);
        bankAccounts[5] = new BankAccount("Conor", "conor1234", 1000);
        bankAccounts[6] = new BankAccount("Tony", "tony1234", 1000);
        bankAccounts[7] = new BankAccount("Eddie", "Eddie1234", 1000);
        bankAccounts[8] = new BankAccount("Justin", "justin1234", 1000);
        bankAccounts[9] = new BankAccount("Ryan", "ryan1234", 1000);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String dih = scanner.nextLine();
    }


    public String getHolder() {
        return holder;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: будьте более конкретны - с чем именно у вас проблемы? Вы считать с косоль ввод не можете? Или поиск по массиву сделать не получается? И зачем вам поиск по массиву, может, лучше поиск по HashMap?

Comment: Не получается сделать поиск по массиву. Нужно именно по массиву)